Cómo guardar datos en dos tablas relacionadas en Django
Buen día, soy nuevo usando Django y estoy siguiendo un tutorial para crear un sistema de escuela. Tengo un CustomUser que se relaciona a tres tablas diferentes por un OneToOneField(), al momento el registrar un usuario, dependiendo del tipo (HOD, profesor, alumno), creo dos señales con @receiver para crear una instancia de la petición POST y luego guardarla en su respectiva tabla.
Problema:

Cuando intento guardar los datos, uso un objeto CustomUser y llamo a la clase create_user() que guardo en una variable user, pero cuando uso ese objeto para guardas otros datos de la tabla que necesito (Teachers en este caso) no se crea el usuario:

def create_teachers(request):
    if auth_user(request) == True:
        # Do something for authenticated users.
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render(request, 'create_teachers.html')
        else:
            try:
                user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
                    password='defaultPass',
                    first_name=request.POST.get('first_name'),
                    last_name=request.POST.get('last_name'),
                    email=request.POST.get('email'),
                    user_type=2,
                )
                user.Teachers.address=request.POST.get('address')
                user.save()
                print('Profesor creado exitosamente')
                return redirect('/auth/create_teachers')
            except:
                print('Error en la creacion de profesor')
                return redirect('/auth/create_teachers')
    else:
        return redirect('../login')

Error en la creacion de profesor
[27/Sep/2024 13:46:14] "POST /auth/create_teachers HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[27/Sep/2024 13:46:14] "GET /auth/create_teachers HTTP/1.1" 200 34724
[27/Sep/2024 13:46:14] "GET /static/css/dist/styles.css?v=1727459174 HTTP/1.1" 200 54543

Si comento la línea user.Teachers.address=request.POST.get('address'), el usuario se crea sin problemas y la instancia en la tabla Teachers se crea con el campo address vacío.
Lo que necesito es entender por qué ocurre el error y como puedo solucionarlo. Había pensado crear un modelo personalizado para cada tabla en lugar de usar un CustomUser y hacer referencia a las otras tablas después, pero no sé qué tan óptima sea esa solución. Cualquier consejo para mejorar el código también es bienvenido. Gracias
# admin.py
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ordering = ('email',)

admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)

# managers.py
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_("The Email must be set"))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_staff=True."))
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_superuser=True."))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

# models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    user_type_data=((1,'HOD'),(2,'staff'),(3,'users'))
    user_type=models.CharField(default=1,choices=user_type_data,max_length=10)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class AdminHOD(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects=models.Manager()

class Teachers(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone=PhoneNumberField()
    address=models.TextField()
    course_id=models.ManyToManyField(Courses)
    subject_id=models.ManyToManyField(Subjects)
    section_id=models.ManyToManyField(Sections)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Students(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idCard=models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    age=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    phone=PhoneNumberField()
    address=models.TextField()
    profile_pic=models.FileField()
    session_start=models.DateField()
    session_end=models.DateField()
    course_id=models.ForeignKey(Courses,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)
    sections_id=models.ForeignKey(Sections,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# Receive a signal to create a new user with certain type
@receiver(post_save,sender=CustomUser)
def create_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type == 1:
            AdminHOD.objects.create(admin=instance)

        if instance.user_type == 2:
            Teachers.objects.create(admin=instance)
            
        if instance.user_type == 3:
            Students.objects.create(admin=instance)

# Save the user
@receiver(post_save,sender=CustomUser)
def save_user_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    if instance.user_type == 1:
        instance.adminhod.save()

    if instance.user_type == 2:
        instance.teachers.save()

    if instance.user_type == 3:
        instance.students.save()


El problema al que se enfrenta es que intenta asignar un valor al campo de dirección al objeto Teachers, pero no crea el objeto Teachers en sí . En Django, cuando usa OneToOneField, primero debe crear un objeto asociado con su usuario antes de poder asignarle un valor.
try:
    user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
        password='defaultPass',
        first_name=request.POST.get('first_name'),
        last_name=request.POST.get('last_name'),
        email=request.POST.get('email'),
        user_type=2,
    )

    # Crear un objeto Teachers y asociarlo con el user
    teacher = Teachers.objects.create(
        user=user,  # se supone que tiene un campo de user en el modelo Teachers
        address=request.POST.get('address')
    )

